# Optimize my Modx snippet with getresources call inside my snippet instead of outside?

Tags: php, code-snippets, modx

SO I have a getResources call giving me an integer value with this call:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`[[*id]]` &totalVar=`totalLinks`]]
```

That outputs to [[+totalLinks]] and I use that to input in to my snippet

```
[[!ChangeNumberToWord? &input=`[[+totalLinks]]`]]
```

My Snippet:

```
$input = '';


function converttoword($total){
    if ($total=="1"){
        $word = "one";
    } elseif($total=="2") {
        $word = "two";
    } elseif($total=="3") {
        $word = "three";
    } elseif($total=="4") {
        $word = "four";
    } elseif($total=="5") {
        $word = "five";
    } elseif($total=="6") {
        $word= "six";
    } elseif($total=="7") {
        $word ="seven";
    } elseif($total=="8") {
        $word = "eight";
    } else{
        $word = "$total";
    }
return $word;                          
}

$output = converttoword($input);

return $output;
```

My question is how I glue these 2 together so I only need to call my snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the getResources call altogether, use: getChildIds in your snippet:

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/class-reference/modx/modx.getchildids

something like:

```
<?php
// current resource ID
$id = $modx->resource->get('id');

// get all child ids
$array_child_ids = $modx->getChildIds($id);

//so you would count that array 
$num_children = count($array_child_ids);

// get rid of the ifs to find the word
$words = array('zero','one','two','three','four','five','six');

// do something if no results
if ($num_children + 1 > count($words)){

    return 'out of range';

}

// return the string
return $words[$num_children];
```

so you have other problems you might need to look at depending on your application:

- what if there are zero children?
- what about resource status or type [published vs. unpublished, symlinks etc]
- what happens if the number of children is 3033 [Three thousand, three hundred and thirty-three]?

[hint: you can google "php convert a number to it's string name" and come up with several options]

Comment: Thanks for this, that will get me going!